# Elastic search exact match query issue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am having a problem while querying elastic search. The below is my query

```
GET _search {
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "name": "SomeName"
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "type": "SomeType"
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "productId": "ff134be8-10fc-4461-b620-79s51199c7qb"
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "request_date": {
                        "from": "2018-08-22T12:16:37,392",
                        "to": "2018-08-28T12:17:41,137",
                        "format": "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSS"
                    }
                }
            }

        ]
    }
}
}
```

I am using three match queries and a range query in the bool query. My intention is getting docs with these exact matches and with in this date range. Here , if i change name and type value, i wont get the results. But for productId , if i put just ff134be8, i would get results. Anyone knows why is that ? . The exact match works on name and type but not for productId

Comment: Could you also post your mappings? Which elasticsearch version do you use? By the way if you need the exact checks, you should implement a term query instead of a match one

Comment: could please give some more information about your query like are you using kibana or any java client  to fetch information

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou , i am not using any mappings. AWS kinesis is writing the entry to ES. depends on the data we pass, it creates the mapping automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the mapping of your productId to `keyword` to avoid the tokenization. With the standard tokenizer `"ff134be8-10fc-4461-b620-79s51199c7qb"` will create `["ff134be8", "10fc", "4461", "b620", "79s51199c7qb"]` as tokens.

You have different options :

1/ use a [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) to check without analyzing the content of the field

```
...
    {
        "term": {
            "productId": "ff134be8-10fc-4461-b620-79s51199c7qb"
        }
    },
    ...
```

2/ if you are in Elasticsearch 6.X you could change your request to

```
...
{
    "match": {
        "productId.keyword": "ff134be8-10fc-4461-b620-79s51199c7qb"
    }
},
...
```

As elasticsearch will create a subfield `keyword` with the type `keyword` for all string field

The best option is, of course, the first one. Always use `term query` if you are trying to match the exact content.

Comment: if i am going with the first solution , can i include multiple term quires ? i need to match up other two items as well . By the way the second solution worked:)

Comment: you can use terms: { productId: ['ff134be8-10fc-4461-b620-79s51199c7qb', 'xxx-xxx-xxxx']}